# matrix performance in C

Tags: c, performance, caching, matrix, memory

i realize a verry large matrix performance between two codes

Code 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct pix{
    unsigned int r,g,b;
};
#define TAM 10000
struct pix color[TAM][TAM];
void main(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<TAM;i++)
        for(j=0;j<TAM;j++){
            color[i][j].r=
            (
                color[i][j].r+
                color[i][j].g+
                color[i][j].b
            ) / 3;
        }
}
```

Code2:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
struct pix{
    unsigned int r,g,b;
};
#define TAM 10000
struct pix color[TAM][TAM];
void main(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<TAM;i++)
        for(j=0;j<TAM;j++){
            color[i][j].r=
            (
                color[j][i].r+
                color[j][i].g+
                color[j][i].b
            ) / 3;
        }
}
```

The only difference between both is the index order(*ij* and *ji*) and they have a large performance difference. Why this happen ?

[Code 1 performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfdtQ.png)

[Code 2 performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RvMC.png)

After a some runs, the avarage of time is:

Code1: 1.541s

Code2: 2.592s

Comment: I noticed a very large matrix performance difference between two codes**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the performance of these matrix multiplications so different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029138/why-is-the-performance-of-these-matrix-multiplications-so-different)

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9936132/3185968

Comment: First code accesses one element per loop, the 2nd accesses two different elements per loop.  Why does a 70% slow down seem unusual?